# Elastic Load Balancer bandwith vs EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

How does pricing with AWS works.

By exemple: 1024 Go of Data Transfer Out in their calculator (http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) cost about 120$.

If you remove this 1024Go and move it in "Total Data Processed by all ELBs", it cost way less, about 30$.

Basically, my question is : Does you pay for transfer being sent from your EC2 to the visitor connected to the ELB? Which price is right?

Comment: Only Amazon can answer this question, and they should do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct and in your example your pricing will actually be $150.

Traffic passed inside AWS regions is free if you use private IP's or DNS Names, except to the ELB.

The ELB will process that $30 worth of data, but then it still must go out to the internet and your users, which will be another $120.

Comment: This is not a correct answer. You pay also for traffic between AZs within the same region (unless it's traffic from/to Amazon S3, Amazon Glacier, Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon SES, Amazon SQS, or Amazon SimpleDB). See https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/ for more details.